# Simple division in R yields wrong result

Tags: r

I encountered a problem with R.

If I insert the following division I get these results.

```
9207550/4
```

Result:

```
2301888
```

But it should be:

```
2301887.5
```

If I add extend numerator and denominator for several zeros, I get the same result:

```
9207550.0000 / 4.0000

2301888
```

Does anybody encounter the same issue? Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Thank you in advance. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `print(9207550/4, digits=10)` so its an optical illusion / default printing quirk. See `?print.default`. Actually, you can type `2301887.5` at the console and also see the rounding.

Comment: You have shown to us the result of the printing. That differs from the result of the calculation. The result of the calculation is as you expected: `x <- 9207550/4; 4*x`

Comment: @Frank thank you for your comment. I see that I misinterpreted the result.

Comment: @jogo I see so the calculations are correct after all. Thanks.

Comment: Those other questions are focused on reducing long decimals. Since this addresses missing digits, I think it warrants its own question. The answers here certainly are different than the answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in `R` to control the number of digit displayed. As an example:

```
options(digits=5)
```

or if you are not a fan of scientific notation then:

```
options(digits = 999)
```

Most systems tend to have some default display precision built in, however that is different from the actual calculation as mentioned by @jogo. `R` is no different from any of those systems when it comes to result rendition.

As far as the calculation is concerned, the base `R` calculation will be sufficient for a most numbers you will deal with in day to day life, however, if you really want to be precise to `n` decimals where `n` can be typically greater than 15, I would suggest using `gmp`, `Rmpfr` or `rcdd` packages.

**EDIT**

I just noticed your attempt at `float` division. Certain language versions like **python 2.xx** have a different treatment of division when it comes to `floats` vs `integers` keeping the storage and computational efficiency in mind for the times it was written. This difference is now gone in the latest version. `R` was built by statisticians for statisticians, so you can rest assured that when it comes to mathematical operations, the default treatment would be any different. Numbers are what they are -- numbers. `Int` and `float` are programmatic constructs, not mathematical ones.